# Programmatic way to run a JUnit5 test repeatedly

Tags: junit5

I would like to run a JUnit5 test programmatically, and I would like to run it multiple times in a loop. I'd like to run class-wide setup and teardown (like `BeforeAll` methods) just once, and then run per-method actions (like `BeforeEach` and the test itself) repeatedly. I'd like the test to repeat until I choose to stop it.

Is this supported by the JUnit5 API? How would I go about doing it?

I'm aware of the [launcher API](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api), but that seems to be oriented toward running the tests just once. If I call this API repeatedly, it does all setup and teardown repeatedly, which is unnecessary and expensive for the tests I'm automating.

Comment: I think perhaps I want to use `Launcher` to create a `TestPlan`, and somehow get my hands on the `Node` objects, and call their `before()`, `execute()`, and `after()` methods as appropriate?

Comment: After a few more hours of looking around, I can't find any way to do this ^ without relying on internal APIs.

Comment: You’re actually asking the Jupiter engine to do something differently than it is wired to do it. I see two options: Either subclass the engine and override the respective code or write an extension and apply it globally.

Comment: @johanneslink - just to clarify: do you think what I'm trying to do wouldn't be expected to work for most tests? I thought it would.

Comment: What I mean is that the launcher API uses an engine as is. If you want to change the engine‘s behaviour you have to tackle it there.

Comment: I'm kinda liking the extension idea. I've done one of those before.